# choose a file from device and upload it to page loaded in the webview

Tags: android, eclipse, browser, android-emulator

In the webview, one page from url is loaded.
and in that page, a button for browse file is there in the name "choose file".
When the user clicks the button, the app should show the gallery to select a file and retrieve it to that page as input.
how can i implement this?

Answer (score 6):

To choose a file:

```
final int CHOOSE_FILE = 1;
//...
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.setType("file/*");
Intent c = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose file");
startActivityForResult(c, CHOOSE_FILE);
```

Then in your onActivityResult:

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
   Uri uri = data.getData();
   String filePath = uri.getPath();
   // here goes the code to upload the file
}
```